# PHP. Как привести объект к типу определённого класса?

Tags: php, типы-данных, приведение-типов

Я пишу на PHP. У меня есть надобность привести из типа object к типу класса, определённого мной. Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: воспользуйтесь стандартным приведением типов. Если не помогло, то нужно писать собственный трансформер из класса в класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, есть так называемые мапперы. Это классы, главная суть которых - перевести значение из типа А в тип Б

```php
class X{
    // some data
}
class Y{
    // some data2
}

class YMapper{
    public function fromX(X $x): Y
    {
        // логика по переводу
    }
}
$x = new X();
$mapper = new YMapper();
$y = $mapper->fromX($x);
```